# Android ListView and multithreading

Tags: android, multithreading, listview

Is it possible to populate `ListView` items from different threads? I mean to say, where each row in the `ListView` is populated from individual thread? I thought of putting `ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` method just after the `run()` method in each thread. The aim is to change the `ListView` item after the respective thread execution is complete. But the problem is, a new `ListView` is instantiated every time a thread is spawned from `MainActivity`. So, all spawned threads think the `ListView` is empty and `ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` updates the first item only. The `ArrayAdapter`, `ListView`, etc are accessed in threads via `MainActivity` context (which I pass as thread constructor each time a new thread has to be spawned).
I'm sorry if the question seems senseless, but I really need a workaround. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: can't get the question..can you provide more information?

Comment: Just wanted to know if I can change each ListView item from a different thread...

Comment: You can use one thread which runs forever...as..public void run(){ while(true){  //ListView updation  }}...this could help